# Include pdf.worker.js in one minified JS file

Tags: gruntjs, minify, pdf.js

PDF.js needs file named pdf.worker.js. That's fine if you include PDF.js into your HTML like `<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>`
PDF.js will look in that very place where pdf.js is stored (in my case, `plugins/pdfjs-dist/build/`) for its worker file.  However, in my case, I'd like to concatenate and minify all of my JavaScript dependencies into one file. (Via Grunt.)

How do I do that for that pdf.worker.js file? How can I include it into my one-and-only JS file?

So, far what I do in Grunt is

```
copy: {
            build: {
                files: [
                    {   src: 'src/plugins/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js',
                        dest: 'dist/name_of_my_app.worker.js'
                    }
                ]
            }
}
```

That works, but it's far from an elegant solution. Aside from looking ugly and the necessity of an additional file, there is a high chance that someone might rename `name_of_my_app` into something else, overlooking that copy process and thus breaking PDF.js

Comment: You can name your worker how you want it just provide correct path at PDFJS.workerSrc .

Comment: @async5 Thanks! But that doesn't help much, since I have two manage a minified and a non-minified version in different directories, I'd like to include the content of the file into another while grunting rather then referencing it.

Comment: So your requirement is to disable worker and include slow parsing logic on main thread?